# PHP Guzzle - How to grab dynamic field from form and post it?

Tags: php, guzzle

I am struggling to solve the following issue:

I have a site I would like to post to, but the site has a hidden field called 'token,' which refreshes with every page refresh.

To successfully post the form, I need that hidden field included in my POST request.

If I do a GET request with GUZZLE, then use preg_match to obtain the 'token' value and then call POST request, I am still getting an error that the token is incorrect.

I assume it is because the form gets refreshed with each GUZZLE call?

Simply can't get my head around it; any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Please add your code and the code of the hidden field.

Comment: That site most likely uses cookies/a session, to actually store information related to the token on the server side. So you will need to receive the cookies and send them back with the next request as well.